# What is the matrix $\left[ DS(A) \right]$, which gives $\left[ DS(A) \right] H=AH+HA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

In Hubbard's multivariable calculus book $DS(A):H \mapsto AH+HA$ is 
introduced as a linear transformation where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, 
$S(A)=A^2$, and $D$ is the notation for derivative. 
It is used to prove that $S$ has a derivative if $\left[ DS(A) \right] H=AH+HA$ using the following limit:

$$\lim_{H \to 0}\frac{1}{||H||}||(S(A+H)-S(A))-\left[ DS(A) \right] H||=0$$

This limit really gives $0$, so S has a derivative. But the actual derivative matrix $\left[ DS(A) \right]$ is not given in the book and I can't see what kind of a matrix gives $AH+HA$ when it is multiplied by $H$. What is this matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using vectorized form $H_v:=\mbox{vec}(H)$ and the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products)
    $\mbox{vec}(AB)=(I\otimes A)\mbox{vec}(B) =(B^{T}\otimes I)\mbox{vec}(A)$ we can write both terms with the $H_v$ on the right
$$
\mbox{vec}(AH+HA)=(I\otimes A)H_v + (A^T\otimes I)H_v,
$$
and find the $n^2\times n^2$ matrix to be  $I\otimes A + A^T\otimes I.$

Comment: This is the first time I have seen matrix vectorization and $n^2\times n^2$ matrices. Can you suggest me an introductory source about this subject?

Comment: @rych: left hand side of your equation is a matrix and the right hand side is a vector

Comment: @i.ozturk. For an introduction I think the linked wikipedia page on Vectorization and Kronecker product should do. Basically, it's whether you're okay with the representation of your matrix-vector H as a stacked column-vector. Actually, we should rather ask Lythia for references on the less trivial subject of tensors of higher order.

Comment: @rych I am not ready for tensors but I think I can comprehend matrix vectorization. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One can do something similar to what you want in the realm of tensors. One can define a "tensor product" of second order tensors, $\odot$, such that for any second order tensors $\boldsymbol{S}$, $\boldsymbol{T}$, and $\boldsymbol{Z}$,
$$\left[\boldsymbol{S}\odot\boldsymbol{T}\right]\boldsymbol{Z}=\boldsymbol{SZT}.$$
Note that $\boldsymbol{S}\odot\boldsymbol{T}$ is a fourth order tensor. With this definition, then
$$\boldsymbol{AH}+\boldsymbol{HA}=\left[\boldsymbol{A}\odot\boldsymbol{I}+\boldsymbol{I}\odot\boldsymbol{A}\right]\boldsymbol{H}.$$

Comment: May be the answer to this question is out of my league and that's why it is not given in the book. I have never learned tensors neither.